# Error on getModuleNameToStackName with Tapestry 5.4 RC

Tags: maven, tapestry

I'm trying to update my frontend from Tapestry 5.3.8 to 5.4-RC1.

When i load the homepage, i get the following stack. In 5.3.8 all is fine. I just changed the tapestry's version in pom and add apache staging repositories

```
<repository>
        <id>apache-staging</id>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/staging/</url>
</repository>
```

Stack :

```
12/02 16:47:37.267 ERROR org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry:208 - java.lang.AbstractMethodError
12/02 16:47:37.267 ERROR org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry:209 - Operations trace:
12/02 16:47:37.267 ERROR org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.Registry:218 - [ 1] Handling page render request for page wallet/Search
12/02 16:47:37.270 ERROR org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule.RequestExceptionHandler:236 - Processing of request failed with uncaught exception: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ajax.JavaScriptSupportImpl.getModuleNameToStackName(JavaScriptSupportImpl.java:340) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ajax.JavaScriptSupportImpl.findStackForModule(JavaScriptSupportImpl.java:328) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ajax.JavaScriptSupportImpl.require(JavaScriptSupportImpl.java:451) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $JavaScriptSupport_b5d849df49dd.require(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at $JavaScriptSupport_b5d849df48c6.require(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ImportWorker$ModuleImport.apply(ImportWorker.java:168) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.transform.ImportWorker$5.advise(ImportWorker.java:197) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.plastic.AbstractMethodInvocation.proceed(AbstractMethodInvocation.java:92) ~[plastic-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Errors.setupRender(Errors.java) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$SetupRenderPhase.invokeComponent(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:174) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$AbstractPhase.invoke(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:133) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.structure.ComponentPageElementImpl$SetupRenderPhase.render(ComponentPageElementImpl.java:181) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RenderQueueImpl.run(RenderQueueImpl.java:79) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageRenderQueueImpl.render(PageRenderQueueImpl.java:121) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $PageRenderQueue_b5d849df492a.render(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at $PageRenderQueue_b5d849df4929.render(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.MarkupRendererTerminator.renderMarkup(MarkupRendererTerminator.java:37) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageNameMetaInjector.renderMarkup(PageNameMetaInjector.java:41) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $MarkupRenderer_b5d849df492c.renderMarkup(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$29.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:1807) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $MarkupRenderer_b5d849df492c.renderMarkup(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$28.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:1797) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $MarkupRenderer_b5d849df492c.renderMarkup(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$27.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:1781) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $MarkupRenderer_b5d849df492c.renderMarkup(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$26.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:1765) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $MarkupRenderer_b5d849df492c.renderMarkup(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.JavaScriptModule$1.renderMarkup(JavaScriptModule.java:265) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $MarkupRenderer_b5d849df492c.renderMarkup(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$25.renderMarkup(TapestryModule.java:1748) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $MarkupRenderer_b5d849df492c.renderMarkup(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.javascript.AddBrowserCompatibilityStyles.renderMarkup(AddBrowserCompatibilityStyles.java:45) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $MarkupRenderer_b5d849df492c.renderMarkup(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.javascript.ConfigureHTMLElementFilter.renderMarkup(ConfigureHTMLElementFilter.java:45) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $MarkupRenderer_b5d849df492c.renderMarkup(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at $MarkupRenderer_b5d849df4928.renderMarkup(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageMarkupRendererImpl.renderPageMarkup(PageMarkupRendererImpl.java:47) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $PageMarkupRenderer_b5d849df4926.renderPageMarkup(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageResponseRendererImpl.renderPageResponse(PageResponseRendererImpl.java:64) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $PageResponseRenderer_b5d849df4921.renderPageResponse(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageRenderRequestHandlerImpl.handle(PageRenderRequestHandlerImpl.java:72) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$34.handle(TapestryModule.java:1974) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $PageRenderRequestHandler_b5d849df4923.handle(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at $PageRenderRequestHandler_b5d849df491e.handle(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.handlePageRender(ComponentRequestHandlerTerminator.java:48) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.DeferredResponseRenderer.handlePageRender(DeferredResponseRenderer.java:52) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_b5d849df491f.handlePageRender(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.services.InitializeActivePageName.handlePageRender(InitializeActivePageName.java:47) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_b5d849df491f.handlePageRender(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestOperationTracker$2.run(RequestOperationTracker.java:73) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationTrackerImpl.run(OperationTrackerImpl.java:56) ~[tapestry-ioc-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.PerThreadOperationTracker.run(PerThreadOperationTracker.java:60) ~[tapestry-ioc-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.RegistryImpl.run(RegistryImpl.java:1254) ~[tapestry-ioc-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestOperationTracker.handlePageRender(RequestOperationTracker.java:66) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_b5d849df491f.handlePageRender(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.tynamo.security.SecurityComponentRequestFilter.handlePageRender(SecurityComponentRequestFilter.java:49) ~[tapestry-security-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
    at $ComponentRequestFilter_b5d849df491c.handlePageRender(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_b5d849df491f.handlePageRender(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at $ComponentRequestHandler_b5d849df48a3.handlePageRender(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.PageRenderDispatcher.dispatch(PageRenderDispatcher.java:55) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $Dispatcher_b5d849df48a9.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at $Dispatcher_b5d849df489a.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$RequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:305) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestErrorFilter.service(RequestErrorFilter.java:26) ~[tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $RequestHandler_b5d849df489b.service(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$3.service(TapestryModule.java:846) [tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $RequestHandler_b5d849df489b.service(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:836) [tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $RequestHandler_b5d849df489b.service(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:89) [tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $RequestHandler_b5d849df489b.service(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:105) [tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:95) [tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withRead(ConcurrentBarrier.java:83) [tapestry-ioc-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter.service(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:119) [tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $RequestHandler_b5d849df489b.service(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at $RequestHandler_b5d849df488b.service(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$HttpServletRequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:256) [tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.tynamo.security.services.impl.SecurityConfiguration$1.call(SecurityConfiguration.java:56) [tapestry-security-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
    at org.tynamo.security.services.impl.SecurityConfiguration$1.call(SecurityConfiguration.java:54) [tapestry-security-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383) [shiro-core-1.2.1.jar:1.2.1]
    at org.tynamo.security.services.impl.SecurityConfiguration.service(SecurityConfiguration.java:54) [tapestry-security-0.5.1.jar:0.5.1]
    at $HttpServletRequestFilter_b5d849df488a.service(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_b5d849df488d.service(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.upload.internal.services.MultipartServletRequestFilter.service(MultipartServletRequestFilter.java:44) [tapestry-upload-5.3.1.jar:na]
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_b5d849df488d.service(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.gzip.GZipFilter.service(GZipFilter.java:59) [tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_b5d849df488d.service(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62) [tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $HttpServletRequestFilter_b5d849df4886.service(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_b5d849df488d.service(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$1.service(TapestryModule.java:796) [tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_b5d849df488d.service(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_b5d849df4885.service(Unknown Source) [na:na]
    at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:166) [tapestry-core-5.4-rc-1.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45) [tomee-catalina-1.6.0.jar:1.6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConGRAVE: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke - "Servlet.service()" pour la servlet default a g�n�r� une exception 
org.apache.shiro.subject.ExecutionException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tapestry5.func.Flow.concat(Ljava/nectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.39]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
util/Collection;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:385)
    at org.tynamo.security.services.impl.SecurityConfiguration.service(SecurityConfiguration.java:54)
    at $HttpServletRequestFilter_b5d849df488a.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_b5d849df488d.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.upload.internal.services.MultipartServletRequestFilter.service(MultipartServletRequestFilter.java:44)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_b5d849df488d.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.gzip.GZipFilter.service(GZipFilter.java:59)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_b5d849df488d.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.IgnoredPathsFilter.service(IgnoredPathsFilter.java:62)
    at $HttpServletRequestFilter_b5d849df4886.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_b5d849df488d.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$1.service(TapestryModule.java:796)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_b5d849df488d.service(Unknown Source)
    at $HttpServletRequestHandler_b5d849df4885.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.TapestryFilter.doFilter(TapestryFilter.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.OpenEJBValve.invoke(OpenEJBValve.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.tapestry5.func.Flow.concat(Ljava/util/Collection;)Ljava/lang/Object;
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.exceptions.ExceptionReportWriterImpl.writeReport(ExceptionReportWriterImpl.java:199)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.exceptions.ExceptionReportWriterImpl.writeReport(ExceptionReportWriterImpl.java:90)
    at $ExceptionReportWriter_b5d849df4955.writeReport(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.exceptions.ExceptionReporterImpl.writeExceptionToFile(ExceptionReporterImpl.java:109)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.exceptions.ExceptionReporterImpl.reportException(ExceptionReporterImpl.java:77)
    at $ExceptionReporter_b5d849df4953.reportException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.renderException(DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.java:240)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.handleRequestException(DefaultRequestExceptionHandler.java:145)
    at org.tynamo.exceptionpage.services.ConfigurableRequestExceptionHandler.handleRequestException(ConfigurableRequestExceptionHandler.java:84)
    at $RequestExceptionHandler_b5d849df4899.handleRequestException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.RequestErrorFilter.service(RequestErrorFilter.java:42)
    at $RequestHandler_b5d849df489b.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$3.service(TapestryModule.java:846)
    at $RequestHandler_b5d849df489b.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$2.service(TapestryModule.java:836)
    at $RequestHandler_b5d849df489b.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.StaticFilesFilter.service(StaticFilesFilter.java:89)
    at $RequestHandler_b5d849df489b.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:105)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter$2.invoke(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:95)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.util.ConcurrentBarrier.withRead(ConcurrentBarrier.java:83)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.internal.services.CheckForUpdatesFilter.service(CheckForUpdatesFilter.java:119)
    at $RequestHandler_b5d849df489b.service(Unknown Source)
    at $RequestHandler_b5d849df488b.service(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tapestry5.modules.TapestryModule$HttpServletRequestHandlerTerminator.service(TapestryModule.java:256)
    at org.tynamo.security.services.impl.SecurityConfiguration$1.call(SecurityConfiguration.java:56)
    at org.tynamo.security.services.impl.SecurityConfiguration$1.call(SecurityConfiguration.java:54)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
```

Edit : Found the problem, i deleted the dependency and it works

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.chenillekit</groupId>
    <artifactId>chenillekit-tapestry</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Had the same problem, and your own solution actually works (for anybody looking). But I didn't want to remove that dependency straight away. It was sufficient to rename the chenillekit* JAR files to xchenillekit* when deployed. 

Obviously order of import is important, but I didn't try to find out why. In the end we will remove the dependency, too, after we clean up those places where it is used.